# SSL_read timeout after select return

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I have a program using C to handle ssl, the steps are as follows:

```
 retval = select(maxfd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
 if (retval ==  -1) {
      //report error
 } else if (retval == 0) {
     // timeout and reconnect

 } else {
     do {
        memset(buf, 0, buf_len);
        count = SSL_read((SSL*)conn->ssl, buf, (int)buf_len);
        if (count <= 0) {
           error("ssl error is %d", SSL_get_error((SSL*)conn->ssl, count))
           error("an error: %s",  strerror(errno));
           break;
         }

      } while (conn->ssl && SSL_pending((SSL *)conn->ssl));

}
```

in some cases, return value of SSL_read is < 0, error number is 5, and error string is read ssl timeout.
why select indicates that socket is ready to read, but SSL_read timeout? how to use select with SSL_read correctly? thanks.

Comment: Are you using non-blocking sockets ? Do you have a timeout on the socket operations ?

Answer (score 2):

select only indicates that there is something on the socket to read. That might be nothing (i.e. peer closed connection) or some data. But for SSL you need more than just data. The payload is encapsulated in SSL frames and SSL_read can only decrypt the frame and return the payload once the full frame is read. Also there are control frames (like handshake or heartbeat...) which do not contain any payload at all.

Thus if select returns that the socket is ready the following things can happen:

- connection close: in this case SSL_read will just return with an error
- incomplete SSL frame: SSL_read will just (blocking) wait for more data. It might return after a while with a read timeout.
- control frames: SSL_read will wait for more frames which actually contain payload and might also return after a while with read timeout.